# Jekyll raw HTML in post

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages, kramdown

I have a Jekyll website, with Posts written in Markdown using the Kramdown parser.

I would like to add some raw HTML within the post. However when I try to add the HTML, it parses it as markdown (changing `<`'s to `&lt;` for example).

I have tried:

- Adding the HTML in its own paragraph.
- Including a `.html` file.
- Adding `markdown="0"` to the HTML tag (also tried `1`).
- Indenting (and wrapping in triple back-tick) with all of the above.
- Using raw tags

Example of what I have:

```
Some **markdown** `here`

<iframe src="asd"></iframe>

More *markdown*.
```

The iframe should be output as HTML, not parsed text.

I am using Github pages, so Jekyll extensions are not optional.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The HTML was being ignored because some tag attr's did not have quotes. For example `width=500` should have been `width="500"`

Nothing else was required. The HTML is in its own paragraphs with no indentation and it is parsed.

Answer (score 9):

For others as reference, to ensure that Kramdown does not process/parse RAW HTML, the attribute `markdown="0"` can be added. This will ensure that the Kramdown parser does not touch the block of HTML tag.

Example:

`Input Markdown:      - hello`

```
Output HTML:

          <ul>
           <li>hello</li>
          </ul>
```

Using the attribute `markdown = "0"`:

`Input markdown:    <div markdown = "0"> - hello </div>`

`Output HTML:       <div markdown = "0"> - hello </div>`

From the [Kramdown documentation](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html) (hint:use your browsers find to look for the keyword 'raw' to jump down to relevant sections):

> If an HTML tag has an attribute markdown="0", then the tag is parsed as raw HTML block.
>
> If an HTML tag has an attribute markdown="1", then the default
>   mechanism for parsing syntax in this tag is used.
>
> If an HTML tag has an attribute markdown="block", then the content of
>   the tag is parsed as block level elements.
>
> If an HTML tag has an attribute markdown="span", then the content of
>   the tag is parsed as span level elements.

Also, all general XML tags are parsed as raw HTML blocks.

Comment: As I said, this did not actually work, I assume it would typically however with the "invalid" HTML being corrected.